# I want to put category name in product page left column top, what to do?

Tags: product, category, magento-1, sidebar, column

I want to add category name in product page left column top, I have created new page called 2columns-left-product.phtml to display a product purpose. Now, I want to display a category name in left column. I just used this code,

[image: code]

but it didn't work for me.

It will return

> fatal error[ Fatal error: Call to a member function getCategoryIds()
>   on a non-object in
>   /home/mtccom/public_html/m/app/design/frontend/default/theme697/template/page/2columns-left-product.phtml
>   on line 100].

Can you guide me to fix this.

I want to add a link to a category, My new code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it sounds like your `$_product` variable is not properly defined.

I reckon you should try adding the following code before the code you pasted:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

Then to get the category URL you can just do:

```
$_categoryUrl = $_category->getUrl();
```

Thus your final code you should like this:

```
if ($_product = Mage::registry('current_product')) {
$_categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
if (count($_categoryIds)) {
    $firstCategoryId = $categoryId[0];
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);
    $_categoryUrl = $_category->getUrl(); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_categoryUrl; ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></a>
<?php }
 } ?>
```

Comment: thanks, it working. But i need to give link to that category name? can you help me?

Comment: @Vijayakumar To get the category URL you can call `$_category->getUrl()`

Comment: can you give me exact code for that

Comment: @Vijayakumar well that is the exact code, see my updated answer

Comment: I tried, <a href="<?php echo $_categoryUrl; ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></a>. it give error [Fatal error: Call to a member function getUrl() on a non-object in /home/mtccom/public_html/m/app/design/frontend/default/theme697/template/page/2columns-left-product.phtml on line 104]

Comment: @Vijayakumar please edit your post with the full code

Comment: reloaded that code, please check it

Comment: @Vijayakumar ok see my reloaded answer

Comment: Put the Mage::registry('current_product'); in if condition.Some time its gives error when user come from featured product from home page.

Comment: @Paarth you're right ive updated my answer

Comment: Some times user comes from featured products from home page then your Mage::registery will not work reason is Mage::Register register product object when comes from category page.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for error is product object is not getting in left side bar. Use below code in catelog xml file.

```
catalog_product_view
   reference name="left"
     block type="catalog/product_view" name="product_catname" template="catalog/product/catname.phtml"
   reference
catalog_product_view
```

you can get the product object using this method $this->getProduct() in catanme.phtml